# Time between interval for trading sessions

Tags: c#, session, datetime

I'm having trouble figuring out which tradings session any particular time is in.

There are four possible sessions, show in this picture taken from ForexFactory.com

[image]

I have this method that I need to check is currentTime is during the specified trading session.

```
public bool IsTradingSession(TradingSession tradingSession, DateTime currentTime)
{

    //Regular session is 5PM - next day 5PM, this is the session in the picture.
    //Irregular sessions also occur for example late open (3AM - same day 5PM)  or early close (5PM - next day 11AM)
    DateTime sessionStart = Exchange.CurrentSessionOpen;
    DateTime sessionEnd = Exchange.CurrentSessionClose;

    if(tradingSession == TradingSession.Sydney)
        return ....... ? true : false;
    if(tradingSession == TradingSession.Tokyo)
        return ....... ? true : false;        
    if(tradingSession == TradingSession.London)
        return ....... ? true : false;
    if (tradingSession == TradingSession.NewYork)
        return ....... ? true : false;

    return false;
}
```

Use:

```
    bool isSydneySession = IsTradingSession(TradingSession.Sydney, CurrentTime);
    bool isTokyoSession = IsTradingSession(TradingSession.Tokyo, CurrentTime);
    bool isLondonSession = IsTradingSession(TradingSession.London, CurrentTime);
    bool isNewYorkSession = IsTradingSession(TradingSession.NewYork, CurrentTime);
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Couldn't you use one of these?  "Methods like IsSamePeriod, HasInside, OverlapsWith, or IntersectsWith are available for convenience to query for special, often used variants of such period relations."

Comment: Nevermind, you are not actually using that library, that threw me off.

Answer (score 1):

First you need the datasource of the DateTimes (start and end) for each market. Then,
based on the argument `currentTime` you can check if it lies within by doing a simple check like:

```
if (currentTime.Ticks >= marketOpen.Ticks && currentTime.Ticks <= marketClose.Ticks)
{
    //Market is open!
}
```

The above is the assumption that `currentTime` is in the same timezone as the market. If it's not, then I'd suggest converting all times in question to UTC so there is no question of whether you have the right timezone.

Comment: Thank you but I get the feeling with this code the same I got with my own attempts, that it seems to simple to account for all cases. 

I added some code at the beginning of my method to be more clear of all possible cases.